# How can you limit the amount of characters in the content box for custom post types in wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom post type: Events

How can I limit the amount of characters allowed in the main content box for this custom post type to 500?

**Update:**
I found this: http://konstruktors.com/blog/wordpress/3685-limit-number-words-characters-in-wordpress-editor/

It's close, though it doesn't target just one type of content, any ideas on how to change this?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498628/how-to-restrict-text-length-of-a-field-while-in-wordpress-editor

Comment: I noticed that, @elclanrs I don't understand it though.. looks a little advanced for me without details or steps :/

Answer (score 1):

Untested. But try:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', limit_text( get_the_content(), 15 ) ); ?>

function limit_text($text, $limit) {
    if (strlen($text) > $limit) {
        $words = str_word_count($text, 2);
        $pos = array_keys($words);
        $text = substr($text, 0, $pos[$limit]) . '...';
    }

    return $text;
}
```

if you want char limit use above the code and you want word limit then use below code

15 is for char limit or word limit? If words, using strlen is incorrect.

Try using WP wp_trim_words() instead.

Trims text to 15 words:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 15, '&hellip;' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Where does this go? It's for characters by the way :)

Comment: Ok, figured out how to use it.. this seems to only limit the characters shown.. I need to actually limit the amount of characters allowed to write in the backend, and it needs to only be for the "event" type. Thanks!